# How do I perform a function on every item in a folder?

Tags: powershell

Very beginner question, but I'd appreciate some help with it.

I have a folder. I have a function, `improve`. I want to apply that function to every file within the folder. I've Googled this simple problem but none of the solutions I've found seem to work. What do I do?

Comment: Info on how to write functions which accept input from the pipeline: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/31/write-powershell-functions-that-accept-pipelined-input.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Something like this -

```
dir -path C:\stuff | ForEach-Object {improve $_}
```

If you make your function support object piping then you can do this -

```
dir -path C:\stuff | improve
```

Here's a simple example how to do that -

```
function improve ($FileItem) {
    process {
        if ($_) {$FileItem = $_}
        Write-Host $FileItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: if the folder contains any subfolders, you will need to add some code to confirm that each `$_` is a file and not a folder.  Something like `| Where-Object {Test-Path -PathType Leaf $_.FullName} |` placed just before the `ForEach-Object` will do this.